# rvm couldn't install in macOS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am following this http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html
to set my RoR environment but unfortunately while installing rvm I am having the following issue, and couldn't resolve it.

[image: screenshot image]

Comment: could you provide commands and outputs you've tried so far ?

Comment: If you could get into the habit of posting console output as text, rather than images, that would be great. Images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines or screen-readers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue its just a warning.

You just need to run the following command in order to load `/.profile`

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: brother after running ~/.profile it shows permission denied

Comment: that's weird you should have permission to do that normally I think. What do you get when you run `ls -lah ~/ | grep .profile`

Comment: [Alis-MacBook-Pro:~ aliahmad$ ls -lah ~/ | grep .profile
-rw-r--r--@   1 aliahmad  staff   217B Nov 23  2015 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--    1 aliahmad  staff   186B Nov 23  2015 .profile
Alis-MacBook-Pro:~ aliahmad$ ](http://code.com) @mjwatts

Comment: lol - I just spotted your mistake you need to run this command: `source ~/.profile` and not run `~/.profile` as that does give a permission denied response.